# Creating Quiz (Quastionare) using Spring MVC + JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

i need your help. My brain will explode without your help! I am writting Quiz app on Spring MVC + JSP.

What i done for now: 
1. I created HashMap + hardcode correct answer. 
2. I created `@RequestMapping(value = "/level_one", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String levelOne() {
        return "levelone";
    }`

How it shoul be:
[pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzIMx.png)

Then i just freezed and i don't know what to do and how to unite this code in @RequestMaping with HashMap and write code in jsp to make it visible and clickable???
In controller i wrote :

```
 package ua.kiev.prog;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

       final private String rightAnswerOne = "Dance";

    @ModelAttribute("answerList")
    public Map answerList() {
        Map<String, String> answerList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        answerList.put("one", "Sandbox");
        answerList.put("two", "Pixel");
        answerList.put("three", "Game");
        answerList.put("four", "Picture");

        return answerList;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/level_one", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String levelOne() {
        return "levelone";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

@modelAttribute is executed before the request mapping. That populate the Model model object (that you didn't pass as a parameter on the method annotated with @requestmapping.

You can access to that object using `model.asMap().Get("yourkey").`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/level_one", method = RequestMethod.POST) public String levelOne(Model model) {
```

model.asMap().get("answerList");
...
return "levelone"; }

This is how modelattribute works but it is a long argument. You might search for some tutorial on spring MVC.
I recommend to Google mkyong spring mvc, he has a huge set of basic tutorials for spring mvc  , easy to understand.

Check this link
http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.I will do it. But on this example, please answer on one more question. If i write code as you wrote before. How should i write jsp page, to unite answers from hash map in the controller and web view? So then if i click on the button on the web, it will be united with hash map on the server side page. 
So then i will be able to write something like this:

```
 public static int getCount(HashMap<String, String> answerList, String rightAnswerOne, String rightAnswerTwo, String message) {
    int count = 0;

    for (String tmp : answerList.values()) {
        if (rightAnswerOne.equals(tmp) ) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        } else {
            System.out.println("DENIED");
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I just want to understand how to write such things.